# Finding multiple functions with same $f_{even}$ but different $f_{odd}$?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

A function can be decomposed as $f(x) = f_{even}(x) + f_{odd}(x)$ where $f_{even}(x)=\dfrac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$ and $f_{odd}(x)=\dfrac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$.

If we know only $f_{even}$, how can we find different values for $f_{odd}$ that work (we can't just plug in any function)? A graphical method works too.

Comment: I don't get it. If you're given $f$ and $f_{\text{even}}$ then $f_{\text{odd}}=f-f_{\text{even}}$ which is to say $f_{\text{odd}}$is uniquely determined.

Comment: @GitGud we're given *only* $f_{even}$, not $f$ or $f_{odd}$.

Comment: What do you mean with "we are given $f_{\text{even}}$"? Do you mean an even function is given? Because saying $f_{\text{even}}$ is given already implies that we're talking about some $f$.

Comment: @GitGud This question comes in the context of doing the inverse DTFT of $Re\{F(\omega)\}$ which gives $f_{even}(t)$. I am trying to find a corresponding expression for $f_{odd}(t)$ that "works" to make a signal $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f$ be your favorite function that isn't even. Then $f(x) \neq f_{even}(x)=(f_{even})_{even}(x)$, and so $f$ and $f_{even}$ are two different functions with the same even part.

Answer (score 2):

There is a one to one correspondence between $A\times B=\{\text{even}\}\times \{\text{odd}\}$ and $C=\{\text{functions}\}$, given by
$$
F(a,b) = a+b
\\
G(f) = \left( x\to \frac{f(x) + f(-x)}2,x\to \frac{f(x) - f(-x)}2 
\right)
$$

In linear algebra terms, $C = A\bigoplus B$.

In other words, $f_{even}$ is not informative **at all** on $f_{odd}$.